# Is it possible to see stack trace of previous crash on launch with Fabric / Crashlytics?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

**The context**

The majority of my app's crashes are in third party code like advertising SDKs. We can test our integration with the SDKs, but there's no way to test everything that our users will see. And with ad SDKs, they are remotely configured and load different ads all the time. A malicious or poorly configured ad seems to be a very common crash.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to detect that the crash was caused by a third party and then disable that SDK for the next session, thereby giving the user a sort of "safe mode" to run the app in so they don't experience crash after crash upon relaunch. I could just do this for all crashes and turn off every SDK, but I'd like to be more deliberate if possible.

**What is possible, as far as I've determined**

If your app crashes, Fabric will tell you through its `CrashlyticsDelegate` methods, e.g. `- (void)crashlyticsDidDetectReportForLastExecution:(CLSReport *)report;`.

These methods give you a `CLSReport` object, which tells you all the information that you set on Crashlytics (e.g. user info, custom keys and more). Unfortunately, this object doesn't tell you anything about the crash itself.

For reference: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html#control-submission-behavior

**My question / feature request**

If I could get the stack trace of the crash, I could easily figure out which SDK caused the crash and decide to not turn that one on. Any ideas how to get this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out about this. This method was created in order to allow for opt-in crash reporting and not for inspection of the stack trace. I'm afraid there isn't a good way to get the stack trace on relaunch. However, I think it's an interesting use case and will let the team know!